# Chrubuntu terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, chrubuntu

I used chrubuntu to install Xubuntu on a new Acer C7 chromebook. One thing that's not working correctly is use of the up-arrow key in the terminal...rather than recall the last command it writes: ^[[A

Anyone know why this is and/or how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know if this will be of use, but this happened to me using Unity on sometimes the keyboard shortcuts got messed up; in my case restarting Unity was the only way. I suspect your issue is different though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal is running sh instead of bash which you are used to. Type `bash` and you will get what you are looking for. To make this permanent when you open up a terminal change your default shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to start a bash shell once, to figure out if the problem is your shell. Type

```
bash
```

in the terminal. If arrow up history now works, you can set bash as your default shell by running the

```
chsh
```

command. This command will prompt you for your password, and then what shell you want to use, for example `/bin/bash`.

If this does not work, you can try another terminal program. One example is the `Gnome Terminal`, which is available in the Ubuntu Software Center.